# Is there aSSH Remote Fowarding source restriction?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote, forwarding

The following command will allow me to view Google.com on localhost:9999

```
ssh user@mywebsite -R localhost:9999:www.google.com:80
```

but the following command will not allow me to view Google.com on 127.1.1.1:9999.

```
ssh user@mywebsite -R 127.1.1.1:9999:www.google.com:80
```

So my question is:

It it a problem with my arguments, os, network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, 127.0.0.1 is routed to localhost and not 127.1.1.1. To use 127.1.1.1, you need to add the following line to `/etc/hosts`:

`127.1.1.1 localhost`

127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255 are all [reserved](http://whois.domaintools.com/127.1.1.1) for localhost loopbacks but only 127.0.0.1 is configured by default on most Unix systems.